# Visual Studio - Is there a way to delete forward one character?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio you can obviously delete backward one character.

Is there a way to delete forward one character?

I've gone through most of the keybinds and can't seem to find one with that functionality anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete backward one character use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and to delete forward one character use <kbd>DELETE</kbd>. It is default behavior of any text editor (and not only)

Comment: Does this go the opposite direction on a right to left language?

Comment: I'm pressing DELETE and it does nothing. Do you know which command it is bound to?

Comment: Please check options Tools - Options - Environment - Keyboard and check Edit.Delete